# Is there a difference between return myVar vs. return (myVar)?

Tags: c#, syntax

I was looking at some example C# code, and noticed that one example wrapped the return in ()'s.

I've always just done:

```
return myRV;
```

Is there a difference doing:

```
return (myRV);
```

Answer (score 230, accepted):

UPDATE: This question was [the subject of my blog on 12 April 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/ericlippert/ignoring-parentheses). Thanks for the amusing question!

In practice, there is no difference.

In *theory* there could be a difference. There are three interesting points in the C# specification where this could present a difference.

First, conversion of anonymous functions to delegate types and expression trees. Consider the following:

```
Func<int> F1() { return ()=>1; }
Func<int> F2() { return (()=>1); }
```

`F1` is clearly legal. Is `F2`? Technically, no. [The spec](https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/csharp%20language%20specification.doc) says in section 6.5 that there is a conversion from a *lambda expression* to a compatible delegate type. Is that a *lambda expression*? No. It's a *parenthesized expression* that contains a *lambda expression*.

The Visual C# compiler makes a small spec violation here and discards the parenthesis for you.

Second:

```
int M() { return 1; }
Func<int> F3() { return M; }
Func<int> F4() { return (M); }
```

`F3` is legal. Is `F4`? No. Section 7.5.3 states that a parenthesized expression may not contain a method group. Again, for your convenience we violate the specification and allow the conversion.

Third:

```
enum E { None }
E F5() { return 0; }
E F6() { return (0); }
```

`F5` is legal. Is `F6`? No. The spec states that there is a conversion from the literal zero to any enumerated type. "`(0)`" is not the literal zero, it is a parenthesis followed by the literal zero, followed by a parenthesis. We violate the specification here and actually allow any *compile time constant expression equal to zero*, and not just literal zero.

So in every case, we allow you to get away with it, even though technically doing so is illegal.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Why the spec violations? I see that you say for convenience but how do you weigh the balance of violating the spec versus being convenient? Was it a bug that became a feature for convenience? :-)

Comment: I think the last word you meant to be *illegal*?

Comment: @Jason: I believe the spec violations in the first two cases are simply errors that were never caught. The initial binding pass historically has been very aggressive about prematurely optimizing expressions, and one of the consequences of that is that parentheses are thrown away very early, earlier than they ought to be. In pretty much every case, all this does is makes programs that are intuitively obvious work the way they ought to, so I'm not very worried about it.  Analysis of the third case is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2006/03/28/the-root-of-all-evil-part-one.aspx

Comment: In theory, in practice, there *is* a difference (I'm not sure if Mono allows these 3 cases, and don't know of any other C# compilers, so there may or may not be a difference in practice in practice).  Violating the C# spec means your code won't be fully portable.  Some C# compilers may, unlike Visual C#, not violate the spec in those particular cases.

Comment: The blog post is now live: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/12/ignoring-parentheses.aspx

Comment: Damn, I'm almost ashamed when I read Lippert insights... I don't think I have knowledge about any subject even close to how much he has about C#.

Comment: @Bruno: All it takes is about eight or ten thousand hours of study of a given subject and you too can be an expert on it. That's easily doable in four years of full-time work.

Comment: @Eric, those are ~80 hour weeks! Take a vacation.

Comment: @Anthony: 8 hours per day x 5 days per week x 50 weeks per year = 2000 hours per year. 8000 hours / 2000 hours per year = 4 years. Where are you getting 80 hour weeks from in there?

Comment: @Eric, I'm getting that number from pure failure, that's where. :( I'm usually good at mental math, but not today. I blame getting old.

Comment: @Anthony: When I do that I just tell people that my degree is in *mathematics*, not *arithmetic*.

Comment: @Eric: for a second there, i read that as 8 or 10 thousand *years* of study! :)

Comment: My heart would totally go for "Don't Violate The Specs Under Any Circumstances". Mainstream languages usually have more than one compiler -we already have mono and MS csc- and this makes specs verification a very necessary facet. This is the only way we can have true portability. The worse part is, once you make such a mistake, you can't revert it because this might break others' code. Bad

Comment: In theory, practice and theory are the same but, in pratice they never are.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the compilers don't follow the spec.  But I checked and Mono (gmcs 2.4.2.3) does allow all 6.

Comment: That third remark explains a problem that baffled me where an integer matched an overload that took an enum instead of being boxed and passed as an object. "The spec states that there is a conversion from the literal zero to any enumerated type" What's the explanation for this? Why, if any, just zero?

Comment: @John: (1) because you need to be able to initialize a set of flags to something; best practice is for the provider of the flags enum to provide a "None" that equals zero but not everyone does. (2) because it seems odd to have an enum field initialized automatically to zero but have no way to check to see if it is still that value without a cast. Due to various issues, we actually allow any constant zero, not just any literal zero, to convert to enum.

Comment: So fix the spec; distinguishing between `expression` and `(expression)` (or `((((expression))))`) is bad language design.

Answer (score 40):

There are corner cases when presence of parentheses can have effect on the program behavior:

1.

```
using System;

class A
{
    static void Foo(string x, Action<Action> y) { Console.WriteLine(1); }
    static void Foo(object x, Func<Func<int>, int> y) { Console.WriteLine(2); }

    static void Main()
    {
        Foo(null, x => x()); // Prints 1
        Foo(null, x => (x())); // Prints 2
    }
}
```

2.

```
using System;

class A
{
    public A Select(Func<A, A> f)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(1);
        return new A();
    }

    public A Where(Func<A, bool> f)
    {
        return new A();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        object x;
        x = from y in new A() where true select (y); // Prints 1
        x = from y in new A() where true select y; // Prints nothing
    }
}
```

3.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Bar(x => (x).Foo(), ""); // Prints 1
        Bar(x => ((x).Foo)(), ""); // Prints 2
    }

    static void Bar(Action<C<int>> x, string y) { Console.WriteLine(1); }
    static void Bar(Action<C<Action>> x, object y) { Console.WriteLine(2); }
}

static class B
{
    public static void Foo(this object x) { }
}

class C<T>
{
    public T Foo;
}
```

Hope you will never see this in practice.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to my question, but still interesting - thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what's going on in 2 here?

Comment: You should elaborate on why this behavior happens.

Answer (score 26):

No, there is no difference other than syntactical.

Answer (score 3):

A good way to answer questions like this is to use Reflector and see what IL gets generated.  You can learn a lot about compiler optimizations and such by decompiling assemblies.

Comment: That would certainly answer the question for the one specific case, but that wouldn't necessarily be representative of the entirety of the situation.

Comment: Disagree. It gives the person a direction to answer the question.