# What is the difference between return and return()?

Tags: javascript

```
function a() { return 1; }
function b() { return(1); }
```

I tested the above code in Chrome's console, and both returned `1`.

```
function c() { return "1"; }
function d() { return("1"); }
```

I also tested the code above, and both of the functions returned `"1"`.

So what is the difference between using `return` and `return()`?

Comment: The answers here will also apply to `void(x)`, `typeof(x)`

Comment: @PaulS.—was always puzzled by `void(0)` since it's supposed to be shorthand for *undefined*. So if it's shorthand, why include unnecessary characters? ;-)

Comment: @RobG I think it's a carry-over from _Python_ and may actually be useful for special cases where you want to include operators `void i = 1; // ReferenceError` vs `void (i = 1); // undefined`

Comment: You might be amused by this question, which is your question applied to C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186595/is-there-a-difference-between-return-myvar-vs-return-myvar/2187498#2187498

Comment: @PaulS. WTF? Python doesn't have a `void` so how can it be a "carry-over"? In fact in python the expression `identifier expr` is *always* a `SyntaxError` (where `expr` doesn't have outer parenthesis).

Comment: @Bakuriu I was thinking of `print(foo)`

Comment: @PaulS. In PHP, I don't like the `print $foo` syntax, but I like the `echo $foo` syntax. I just feel it should be `print($foo)` rather than `print $foo`. I feel like it's a function, whereas `echo $foo` is a command; reminiscent of my DOS days.

Comment: @Alma Do: Since there are no "thanks" answers etc, there is no reason to protect this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use parentheses when returning in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824558/why-use-parentheses-when-returning-in-javascript)

Comment: Why not post a question asking what the difference is between `a` and `(a)`. Maybe you get 94 upvotes on that one too.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

The same as between

```
var i = 1 + 1;
```

and

```
var i = (1 + 1);
```

That is, nothing. The parentheses are allowed because they are allowed in any expression to influence evaluation order, but in your examples they're just superfluous.

`return` is not a function, but a *statement*. It is syntactically similar to other simple control flow statements like `break` and `continue` that don't use parentheses either.

Comment: Then how does `return` work? In any other function, you need a pair of parentheses to indicate the arguments. Why do you not need the parentheses to indicate the return value in `return`?

Comment: A [*return statement*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9) can be followed by an expression. A return must be in a function, so the function returns the value of the expression, or if there isn't one, *undefined*.

Comment: @chris97ong: return is not a function.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Who says we can't make it one ;)

Comment: If you made `return` into a function, how would you return a value from it?

Comment: This is a great answer with a great example, but I think it may be worth adding that 'return' isn't a function into the main answer - considering that it's the root of the misunderstanding that led to this question.

Comment: @BiscuitBaker: I added a bit. When I jotted down this short answer I did *not* expect it to get 50+ upvotes...

Comment: @dan04 `window['return'] = function(x) {return x;}`. `window['return'](123)` returns 123 :)

Comment: "Who says we can't make it one" -- logic.

Answer (score 22):

There is no difference.

`return` is not a function call, but is a language statement.  All you're doing with the parentheses is simply grouping your return value so it can be evaluated.  For instance, you could write:

```
return (x == 0);
```

In this case, you return the value of the statement `x == 0`, which will return a boolean `true` or `false` depending on the value of `x`.

Comment: [*return*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.1) is a keyword that signifies the start of a [*return statement*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9).

Comment: The evaluation of the return statement needs no "grouping". So in any case there will be a boolean return.

Answer (score 19):

Actually here precedence of `()` is higher so it evaluate first:

Here firstly `("1")` get evaluated, in following way:

```
("1")                     ==> "1"
("1","2")                 ==> "2"
("1","2","3")             ==> "3"
("1"+"2","2"+"2","3"+"2") ==> "32"
(2+3+6)                   ==>  11
```

so above statement is equivalent to:

```
return "1";
```

See visually:

> [image: viusal]

So there is basically no difference in functionality but second one might be a negligibly bit slow as it firstly solve the brackets.

Comment: Why would you make a completely unverified assertion that "second one might be a negligibly bit slower" when that is not the case?

Answer (score 9):

There is no difference, the parenthesis are optional. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22a685h9):

> ```
> return[(][expression][)];
> ```
>
> The optional expression argument is the value to be returned from the function. If omitted, the function does not return a value.
>
> You use the return statement to stop execution of a function and return the value of expression. If expression is omitted, or no return statement is executed from within the function, the expression that called the current function is assigned the value undefined.

Comment: Only MS would think to make grouping "optional" in a [*return statement*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9). They are as "optional" there as in any expression, or many other parts of the grammar.

Comment: @RobG: But apparently, they're far more likely to be asked about in a `return` statement.  :P  MS probably got tired of fielding the question from JS noobs.

Comment: There *is a difference* for the reader. And the odd idea that return could be a function arises from using parentheses.

Comment: The M$ explanation is incorrect. The `()`, is not part of the return statement.

Comment: "There is a difference for the reader."  Well, yes: The MSDN spec **erroneously** implies that `return (expression` and `return expression)` are legal.

Comment: @JimBalter Along with `return ()`, `return  (` and `return )` :P

Answer (score 9):

There is absolutely no difference. If you will look at JS (ECMAScript) [specification of return](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9) statement. Among many other things, it is telling you :

> return [no LineTerminator here] Expression ;

that you can provide expression to `return`. Expression is `hello`, `Math.abs(x)`, `yourCustomFunc(7)`, or in your second case this can be `1` or `(1)`. Expression `1` after evaluation is the same as `(1)` and the same as `(((((1))))))` or even as something really bizarre like `(+(!(+(!1))))`.

Comment: +1 for the official reference. Isn't there a page-by-page reference? - The one-page HTML loads very long.

Comment: @Wolf I have not found such. Here is another one, but it is also one page https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-return-statement

Comment: Yes, sad. I'd also no success. What about expanding your quote to the whole syntax of the return statement?

Answer (score 9):

**`return`** is <s>a statement</s> [a keyword that starts the return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23034078/617937), **not a function.**

As has been mentioned, the extra parentheses affect evaluation order, but are not used to "execute" the function named `return`. That is why these lines work without any problems:

```
return (1);
var a = (1);
```

They are, in effect, identical to these lines:

```
return 1;
var a = 1;
```

The reason `return()` throws a syntax error is for the exact reason [the following line throws an error](http://jsfiddle.net/IQAndreas/5GjnL/) (return statement included for comparison):

```
return();    // SyntaxError: syntax error
var a = ();  // SyntaxError: syntax error
```

Comment: And just as a side note, if `return` doesn't include anything after it, it assumes you wanted to return `undefined`.

Comment: @Wolf The expressions is optional, so `return` by itself is a return statement.

Answer (score 5):

There is huge difference for humans, and zero difference for Javascript engine.

`return 1` is a *statement* declaring that we need to immediately exit the function yielding value of 1.

`return(1)` is the same statement disguised as the *function call* by the idiotic convention that you are not obliged to insert space outside of parentheses in Javascript. If you would use code like this in production system, any maintainer will come to your office with stake and torches, after spending some time trying to decide whether you do really have `return()` function somewhere in codebase or just don't know what `return` keyword is for.

As many other people have already correctly said, parentheses do nothing except "group" with higher precedence the literal for the number `1`.

Comment: "There is huge difference for humans" -- Not competent ones. " the same statement disguised as the function call" -- there is no `return` function. "the idiotic convention that you are not obliged to insert space outside of parentheses in Javascript" -- almost no language requires that; calling this idiotic is idiotic. "any maintainer will come to your office with stake and torches" -- no competent one would. `return(1)` is poor practice but people who get upset about such things are wasting resources and creating a bad atmosphere.

Comment: @JimBalter "Not competent ones" -- ha! "Almost no language requires that" -- that's why I said "convention". If it's idiotic, it's called "idiotic". "There is no `return` function" -- the fact that interpreter will forbid you from registering a function with name `return` will not help the reader of the code not to question his sanity first, so, this code is waste. `return(1)` is not just "poor practice", is a dangerous sign of someone not knowing what he's doing!

Comment: So you either don't know what "obliged" means, or you're changing your claim ... either way I won't waste any more of my time on you.

Comment: I doubt the troth of your last sentence; `return` has (in all languages I know that have this keyword) least precedence. So, if the optional expression is present, it is always evaluated first.

Answer (score 4):

In the return statement, the **parentheses** around the expression **are already built in.**

In JavaScript, as in many other languages (like C, C++, Java, Python), the return statement has two parts: the keyword `return` and an (optional) expression. So in, any case, **all that is following the `return` keyword is *first* evaluated as an expression**, after that, the return statement is "executed" by passing the control back to the caller.

To use or not to use parentheses is a **matter of style**, whereas most style guides forbid them for trivial cases like the one quoted in your question, because it makes return falsely looking like a function.

**Later addendum**

If with parentheses or without, never forget to place the optional expression behind the `return`, that is, in the same line. The **real pitfall** with `return` in JavaScript lies in adding a line break after it:

```js
function test() {
  return 
  1;
}
```

... because above `test` function will return [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

Answer (score 2):

by adding parenthesis, we have made sure that javascript doesn't insert a semicolon before multiple statements written after return,
for reference:-
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion

**example**:

`return
 a + b;`

is transformed to

`return;
 a + b;`

by ASI.

The console will warn "unreachable code after return statement".
To avoid this problem (to prevent ASI), you could use parentheses:

`return (
     a + b
     );`

code copied from:- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: This is absolutely correct and that way it makes sense for complex expressions. But you should add *on the same line* or *directly behind return* in the first sentence to make it even more clear. I think that the downvote comes from misinterpretation of this.