# What is the difference between function and keyword/statements?

Tags: python, function, keyword, difference, definition

I've seen 'del' being referred to as a **keyword** and as a **statement**. Apparently, it is not considered a **function**:

> Python has a del statement (keyword) to delete objects, **not a del function**.

https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/python/del-function-in-python-code/

I looked up the definition of a function in Python and it says:

> In Python, a function is a group of related statements that performs a specific task.

Under this definition, I do not understand how del cannot be considered a function.

It does perform a specific task: deleting an item at a given index.

The **syntax** appears to be different, as you don't need parentheses to use the del statement:

```
motorcycles = ['honda', 'suzuki', 'yamaha']
del motorcycles[0]
```

But what are the other practical consequences of del being a statement/keyword rather than a function?

Finally, the **main question** here is: **how do I identify** something as a statement rather than a function and vice versa?

Considering that I'll have to know that in order to know the syntax needed, I think it is quite important for me to understand that.

I did some research and I found a few explanations to why functions are different than keywords:

> Function is a lower designation than a keyword interaction - and in of itself - has to call higher designated System operative calls or akin - to fundamentally interact with memory partitioning.
>
> The main reason for this - is how Python’s hierarchy is constructed in of itself.

But to me - a beginner in Python whose first programming language is R - that does not seem to help me identify something as a keyword instead of a function.

Plus, if a statement is different than a keyword, how is it that I've seen del being referred to as both a statement AND a keyword?

([What is the difference between a statement and a keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034078/what-is-the-difference-between-a-statement-and-a-keyword))

Can anyone shed some light on this, please? I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: I think that `del` is a statement because it is not called, whereas functions have to be called to get the `group of related statements` to run.

Comment: @quamrana is right since statement performs an action (in this case deleting objects). Additionally, `del` is not a function because a function (as you said it) comprise of group of related statements that performs a specific task. `del` is a single statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python keywords are essentially `special reserved words that have specific meanings and purposes and can’t be used for anything but those specific purposes.` They come with the python standard library and you cannot change them in anyway. You can read more about keywords [here](https://realpython.com/python-keywords/) If you run `help("keywords")` in your python interpreter, a bunch of keywords will be returned, and `del` is one of them.

Python statements refer to any line/lines of python code (which include stuff such as `del motorcycles[0]` and `print(motorcycles[0])`), and they do not have to meet any specific conditions to be classified as statements.

Python functions refer to a block of reusable code that does something and can returns a value each time they are run. They can either come with the standard library or be defined by users. You can refer to [this](https://realpython.com/defining-your-own-python-function/) for more information about functions.

`Del` in python is a keyword as it does something a normal python function cannot do: it interacts with the underlying memory and unbinds the variable from the memory. It is implemented with CPython.

Comment: what do you mean when you say del interacts with the underlying memory? Could you give me an example?

Comment: This question would require a deeper understanding of how python works. This answer gives us a good understanding of how del is implemented in python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21053433/14850526