# Why does throw work when written as a function (e.g. throw("blah") works like throw "blah")?

Tags: javascript

According to MDN, [throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) is called with an expression (like `throw "blah"`). Recently I saw a usage of `throw` as a function: `throw("blah")`, and this worked fine.

My guess is that it's not actually being called as a function. Instead, it's processing `("blah")` into the string `blah` and then calling throw with that string expression. Is that the case, or is there some fall-back for `throw` as a function?

Comment: Your guess would be correct. `throw("foo")` is the same thing as `throw "foo"`.

Comment: Parenthesis are useless as they are in `1+1` equivalent to `(1+1)`. Sorry for the dup flag, it is about `c++` and not js.

Comment: It’s the same as [What is the difference between `return` and `return()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22988640/4642212).

Comment: Thanks for the help folks! The `return` and `return()` question is probably the closest dup of this, but the other responses help too.