# About Anonymous Functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new in Javascript, but have deep background real OO languages like C#, Java, C++...
In Javascript there is a concept called anonymous functions. Here is a sample code:

```
(   function() { 
      for(var x = 0;x<5;x++) {
         console.log(x); 
      } 
   })();
```

As I have understood the parantheses at the end make the function call itself.
There is also another syntax which does the same:

```
var x =   function() { 
      for(var x = 0;x<5;x++) {
         console.log(x); 
      } 
   }();
```

But right now if I try to use `x`, it does not execute the function again. So what is the goal if using the assignment in the second version? Can I use the function via `x` again?

Comment: Since you have `()` after function, it will call it immediately and assign its return value (*in your case, undefined*). Remove `()` and if you want to call it immediately, make a call on next line like: `x();`

Comment: Beware that JavaScript is not object oriented. Instead, JS is prototype oriented and there will be things that surprise you.

Comment: why someone downvoted this question? it is a good question for beginners

Comment: The first one without `var x  = `is actually an IIFE  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript

Comment: var x is the result of calling that anonymous function ... which, in this case ... is `undefined` as it has no return

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Self executing function are known as IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression), it is usually used to control the scoping so you don't end up with a lot of global variables.

For example, this function act as a moneybox, it encapsulate all information of your "money", so you can only insert money or get the total money, but you can't directly call add/get and access the variable.

It can be used as a form of OOP as well, since you are already very familiar with it

```js
var myMoneyBox = (function() {
    var money = 0;

    function addMoney(x) {
        if (x > 0)
            money += x;
    }

    function getMoney() {
        return money;
    }

    return {
        add: addMoney,
        get: getMoney
    }
})();

myMoneyBox.add(10);
console.log(myMoneyBox.get());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That made the concept much more clearer

Answer (score 2):

`x` is assigned the *result* of your function, just like in any other expression `x = f()`, you just define `f` within the expression. It doesn't have a return value so in this case the value of `x` is `undefined`.

If you want to use `x` to *call* the function, then just don't add the `()` to the end of the expression...

Comment: May be opinionated comment, but this should have been a comment

Comment: Comments are for asking clarification, this is an actual answer. What you mean is that the answer is so simple that this should never have been a question, and there I agree.

Comment: If you think that should not be a question here, where should I ask this question when I have it? (Btw thanks for the answer, now it is clear)

Comment: @CodePope: a bit more playing around with the code on your own in a browser's console would also have done it, so it's a bit low effort. But I was procrastinating and your question was on top :-). Amusingly the high voted and accepted answer completely ignores your question and explains something else.

Comment: @Rajesh: whenever there is a risk I take myself too seriously, I remember what my highest voted answer is ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988640/what-is-the-difference-between-return-and-return/22988680#22988680 ) and then I can only laugh...

Answer (score 2):

I think this could help you:

```js
var x =   function() { 
      for(var x = 0;x<5;x++) {
         console.log(x); 
      } 
   }; 
x();
```